# Set digest_size when using hmac module

Tags: python-3.x, hmac, hashlib

How to set `digest_size` here?

```
hmac.new(b'asdf', b'asdfasdf', hashlib.blake2b).hexdigest()
```

I've tried this to no effect:

```
h = hmac.new(b'asdf', b'asdfasdf', hashlib.blake2b)
h.digest_size
64
h.hexdigest()
'ad6ccffb7c84f3f2c39d1426a395bd89d340d00d5f04e2dd02d0467181d2aff961a890cc6beda987ded2c120bf359bf45500fdf6c0d60ce8abe110a8f0696c72'
h.digest_size=16
h.hexdigest()
'ad6ccffb7c84f3f2c39d1426a395bd89d340d00d5f04e2dd02d0467181d2aff961a890cc6beda987ded2c120bf359bf45500fdf6c0d60ce8abe110a8f0696c72'
```

In a similar vein to this when used with the `hashlib` module:

```
hashlib.blake2b(b"asdfasdf", digest_size=16).hexdigest()
```